Cannot add Blazor Web Assembly project to ASP.NET Core 6 application
I need to add Blazor Web Assembly project to an ASP.NET Core 6 application.
I did as described in this article How to integrate Blazor application

Removed builder.RootComponents.Add<App>("#app"); from Program (Blazor)
Added Blazor project to ASP.NET Core project as reference
Installed Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Server package in the ASP.NET Core app. The version is 6.0.32.
Added app.UseWebAssemblyDebugging();app.UseBlazorFrameworkFiles(); app.MapFallbackToFile("index.html"); to Startup in ASP.NET Core
Added <script src="_framework/blazor.webassembly.js"></script> to _Layout.cshtml in ASP.NET Core
Added Blazor component to view: <component type="typeof(Counter)" render-mode="WebAssemblyPrerendered" />.

The component is displayed on the page (view) but when I click button nothing happens (must be counter increased).
Before integrating Blazor Web Assembly project I used Blazor Server in my ASP.NET Core application. But before new update I removed it and all  its setup statements (like services.AddServerSideBlazor();).
What can be wrong?
Thanks.

I think we'd need to see your code rather than a bullet list summary of what you've tried. See [mcve] for the content you'll need to add as text (not images) to your question.

Tested with the link article and the steps are right, whether .net 6 or 7 works. Please check the log information of your web and provide more detailed information about your steps. For example, nudget package version , whether .net core app migrated and  other details not mentioned

I created new ASP.NET Core .NET 6 application and integrated new Blazor WebAssembly Standalone App .NET 6 as described in this article. All works fine. I could add Counter component to view and button click increases counter.
